# Changing lists in Python

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

```
#Case 1
myList=[1,2,3,4]
old=myList
myList=[5,6,7,8]
print(old)

#Case 2
myList=[1,2,3,4]
old=myList
myList[0]=10
print(old)

#Case 3
myList=[1,2,3,4]
old=myList.copy()
myList[0]=10
print(old)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[10, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For me the case 3 is the safe case and Case 2 is clear. However, I am not able to clearly understand why in case 1 `old` is not changed.

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case 1, we are re-assigning a brand new list to the name `myList`. The original list that was assigned to `myList` is not affected by this operation; `myList` is now simply pointing to a different object

This becomes clear when we look at the ids of the objects:

```
>>> myList = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print(id(myList))
47168728
>>> old = myList
>>> print(id(old))
47168728
>>> myList = [5,6,7,8]
>>> print(id(myList))
47221816
>>> print(id(old))
47168728
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `old = myList` does not bind the two variables inextricably; it assigns the *value* of `myList` to `old` *at that point in time*. By reassigning `myList` to a new list afterwards, you are then making `myList` and `old` point to different values.